# Help selecting dedicated server with good disk I/O & network

Tags: server, looking-for-hosting, dedicated-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I am looking for a cheap dedicated server. (I was earlier happy with VPS, until I realized that the disk I/O is not at all reliable and depends on what your neighbours are up to at the moment).

I was browsing through http://www.lowenddedi.net/the-database

I don't understand memory speed and NIC speed columns at all. What will be their affect? Do I need to worry about them?

Also, can someone help suggest a provider, with following criteria:

1) Good & reliable Network

2) Price <= $60/month.

Comment: you could always pick a dedicated server by ram and convert ram to high speed disk

Comment: That is a good idea, and I planned to do it also. By the way - do you think I could do the same on a Xen VPS? VPS plans with equivalent memory (and server specs) are cheaper, but I am not sure VPS RAM performance would be as good as dedicated server RAM performance.  As I plan to eliminate disk I/O, all I would need is a VPS with good ram performance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at Cloud Computing, rather than a dedicated server. Reasons for this are that you only pay for what you use, and the fact it is "in the cloud", you have a number of servers hosting your site instead of just the one.

Several companies offer this, such as Amazon and (soon) Ubuntu. From memory, it's something like $0.10 per something. Can't remember if it's per megabyte or per hour.

Comment: Aha. I had a related question http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7713/could-hosting-disk-io-question . Is cloud hosting disk I/O comparable to a VPS disk I/O or more like a dedicated server disk I/O?

Comment: I think it would be comparable with a dedicated server disk I/O, just for the sheer fact your website is distributed over many servers. A bit like having $100 in the bank, but having $20 in one bank, $20 in another etc.

Comment: RE: "you only pay for what you use" but you pay *more* for what you use. [VPS hosting is still cheaper](http://matthewphiong.com/price-war-linode-vs-slicehost-vs-amazon-ec2-v) than the most popular "cloud" solutions and JP19 has indicated that cost is a concern.

Comment: Yes but as Cloud computing allows scalability, the more it is used the more cost effective it becomes. VPS is cheaper, but is it actually better? Once you start to reach the limits of the VPS hosting, you have to change to a more powerful server, and incur more costs. You could also be paying £200 a month for VPS for hosting your not really using, whereas if you use Cloud computing for the same amount of low demand you would end up paying less for what your using.